# What is meant by 'intellectual infrastructure'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-edit-page/modis-middle-class-muddle-failure-to-amend-flawed-rte-act-shows-ndas-disconnect-with-its-most-articulate-supporters/)

> Lacking the **intellectual infrastructure** to think through policies on its own, BJP often just toes the Congress line, even when this explicitly goes against the party’s own **stand in opposition** and outrages its supporters.

Also, what is 'stand in opposition'.

I think the sentence is grammatically perfect but Grammarly shows up a problem with the possessive used with the party.

Comment: I'm guessing that "Grammarly" is some sort of automatic grammar checker. As such it is very possible that words are being processed incorrectly. My first guess would be that it is processing the word "stand" as a verb and therefore doesn't accept a possessive noun + verb.

Comment: Also stand(noun) can mean: 31. a determined policy, position, attitude, etc., taken or maintained. It is referring to the political party's policies.

Comment: @Leo I guess the problem it (Grammarly) spotted was more trivial than that, i.e., it saw *party* wasn't a living thing, so it thought using the *'s* with it was wrong.

Comment: Yeah but you don't need to be a living thing to be able to have a possessive. Ex: "My car's windshield is cracked."

Comment: @Leo Very true indeed. I guess Grammarly follows that kind of rule given by some style manual or something. (Whether or not this and other rules are good is another matter.)

Comment: I would use the word **stance** rather than **stand**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, about "intellectual infrastructure":

Look at the definition of infrastructure [in this dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infrastructure).  In this case, we use the first meaning - the general underlying framework, physical or not, to support any system.  In this case, that system is a political party (the BJP).

So "intellectual infrastructure", in the context of a political party, would mean things such as think tanks, advocacy groups, political journals, political philosophers, newspaper editorial boards, etc. - the intellectual support for the political party.  The author is saying that the BJP doesn't have these.

Answer (score 1):

An *infrastructure* is comparable to a skeleton - it provides the base that something can be built on, but also allows things built on it to move around and develop/grow/flourish.  A bad infrastructure will limit the extent or speed at which something can develop or change.

> Lacking the intellectual infrastructure to think through policies on its own, BJP often just toes the Congress line, even when this explicitly goes against the party’s own stand in opposition and outrages its supporters.

*Stand* is a noun meaning "official point of view".

*X in opposition* means "against and attempting to fight/overcome a existing established X"

Your tool may be thinking *stand* is a verb, which it is not.  The possessive determiner *own* is OK with *stand* as a noun.